# How can I fix this problem with TypeError

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I have typescript code. When click some button there must be working some func. That bounded with `componentwillmount`.

```
componentWillMount() {
    const { species } = this.props;
    const selectedSpecies =
    species.find(v => v.id == SPECIES_TYPE_CATTLE) || null;
    if (selectedSpecies) {
      this.onSpeciesSelect(selectedSpecies);
     }
}
```

> TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'species.find')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check for `species` before doing `.find`.

```
const selectedSpecies = species ? species.find(v => v.id == SPECIES_TYPE_CATTLE) : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

selectedSpecies is probably result of an async action and its value is not available at the time that componentDidMount is doing its job. So it should have a default value or be checked before that has a value